# df says free space, but no space to create file

Tags: mount

I have a hdd attached to my raspberry pi and it is mounted on /media/hdd/ by the following line in the /etc/fstab:

```
/dev/sda1 /media/hdd  vfat uid=www-data,gid=www-data 0 0
```

I have the user www-data upload a lot of files to that directory, but already after a few GB the proces that is supposed to write these files gives an error that there is no more space in the directory.

Indeed when I run copy on the last file I get an error:

```
/media/hdd $ sudo cp existing_file copied_file
cp: cannot create regular file `copied_file': No space left on device
```

But then when I check there is a huge amount of space left!:

```
df -h .
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       1.9T  4.6G  1.9T   1% /media/hdd
```

ls | wc -l indicates there are about 21800 files in the folder. All of similar size.
So I have absolutely no idea why neither my program or sudo can create new files on the disk, even though the disk is supposed to be almost empty. However, I can still create a tiny text file..

What is going on here?

EDIT:

```
pi@raspberrypi /media/hidden_uploads $ df -i .
Filesystem     Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sda1           0     0     0     - /media/hdd
```

Comment: can you post the output of `df -i`? Maybe the partition has ran out of inodes.

Comment: I would say your partition is being mounted as read-only due to an error. Do a `fsck` then create a empty file (with `touch`) as `root`.

Comment: Is there a quota in effect on your system? Does `cat /etc/fstab | grep quota` produce any output?